# progress event in a for loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I want to add different progress bars for multiple file uploads.
See the code below

```
//Suppose total files uploaded = 5
for(i= 0; i < 5; i++){
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(){console.log(i)},false);
    .....
    }
```

In console it prints only 5 .Can some one explain why it doesn't print 0.1.2.3.4.
When first file is being uploaded . It should show 0 . & same for 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 files
How can i separate progress for each file?

Comment: `console.log[i]` doesn't make any sense, check your code.

Comment: sorry console.log(i)

Comment: Because the loop is executed much faster than the callbacks and at that time `i` is 5.